# in MySQL Workbench, how do I create a mysql server on my localhost?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysql-workbench

*In this question I am using Windows 7 32-bit, and MySQL Workbench 5.2.35 CE Rev 7915*

I'm trying to create and connect to a mysql database on my localhost.  It seems obvious.  I should start up Workbench, go to Server Administration -> New Server Instance, tick the 'localhost' radio button and follow the wizard.  But I get to the 'Test DB Connection' step and it fails to 'Open Database Connection'.  The Message Log says:

Connecting to MySQL server localhost...
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Now, my question is this:  Am I supposed to have already installed and started up a MySQL server on my localhost with some tool or program other than Workbench?  It seems like this wizard is just supposed to create a connection to an already existing mysql server, but I don't know how to create a server on my localhost.  I hoped Workbench would provide a way to do all of this:  Create MySQL server, start it up, connect to it, query it, etc.  but it seems like maybe it can only connect to already existing servers.

What should I do to create a MySQL server on my local machine and connect to it with MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Workbench is just a front-end. You do need to have the server software installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. MySQL Server and MySQL Workbench are separate products, as Workbench is a GUI to the Server. To install both, download "[MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)" and (by default) it will install both (and other) MySQL products.